# Swift: Default function parameter value via NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a function with default parameter value like this:

```
@objc func myFunc(theFlag: Bool = false) {

}
```

This function is called via notification center

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFunc), name: MyNotificationName, object: nil)
```

When MyNotificationName is posted, *myFunc* is called via notification center.

I assumed that the default value of *theFlag* is set to "false" and it works as I expected on most devices. 
However, I found that *theFlag* is set to "true" on 32bit devices.

I wonder if this was not a correct way to call a function with default value via notification center.  Is there any official manner to do that?

I'm testing on Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is

```
@objc func myFunc(_ notification:Notification) // OR NSNotification also
```

Don't expect the `NotificationCenter.default` to set a value for `theFlag: Bool = false` , with

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFunc), name: MyNotificationName, object: nil)
```

OR

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFunc(_:)), name: MyNotificationName, object: nil)
```

//

If you want to send a value then insert it inside `object` / `userInfo`

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name:MyNotificationName, object:<#Here#>, userInfo:<#OrHere#>)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was ignoring the official rule that selector must have one and only argument "NSNotification"

Comment: with similar issues you can think of as there is no way to send a value , then there shouldn't be a parameter for that , e.x when you add target to a button or any UI component then the one and only , parameter of the selector function should be of same type ,  It can be **Any** but the cast will only succeed with target element